# Oracle - how to insert if not exists?

Tags: oracle, insert

Example dB : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=49af209811bce88aa67b42387f1bb5f6

I'd like to add insert this line

1002    9   1   UNKNOWN

Because of the line exists

1002    5   1   JIM

I was thinking about something like
select codeclient from STATS_CLIENT_TEST where CODEAXESTAT=5
and insert codeclient, 9,1,UNKNOWN.

but not sure how to do it? And simple query or a PL/SQL?

What's the best way to get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `INSERT .. SELECT` statement with a `PARTITION`ed outer join:

```sql
INSERT INTO stats_client_test (
  codeclient, codeaxestat, codeelementstat, valeuraxestatistiqueclient
)
  SELECT cc.codeclient,
         s.codeaxestat,
         s.codeelementstat,
         'UNKNOWN'
  FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT codeclient FROM stats_client_test) cc
         LEFT OUTER JOIN stats_client_test s
         PARTITION BY (s.codeaxestat, s.codeelementstat)
         ON (s.codeclient = cc.codeclient)
  WHERE  s.rowid IS NULL;
```

or a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO stats_client_test dst
USING (
  SELECT cc.codeclient,
         s.codeaxestat,
         s.codeelementstat,
         s.ROWID AS rid
  FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT codeclient FROM stats_client_test) cc
         LEFT OUTER JOIN stats_client_test s
         PARTITION BY (s.codeaxestat, s.codeelementstat)
         ON (s.codeclient = cc.codeclient)
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (codeclient, codeaxestat, codeelementstat, valeuraxestatistiqueclient)
  VALUES (src.codeclient, src.codeaxestat, src.codeelementstat, 'UNKNOWN');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=931671e7323e65b3d84904476bf979ed)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option: using the `MINUS` set operator, find missing `codeclient` values and then insert appropriate row(s).

Before:

```
SQL> select * From stats_client_Test order by codeaxestat, codeclient;

CODECLIENT           CODEAXESTAT CODEELEMENTSTAT VALEURAXESTATISTIQUECLIENT
-------------------- ----------- --------------- ----------------------------------------
1000                           5               1 JOHN
1001                           5               1 ALICE
1002                           5               1 JIM
1003                           5               1 BOB
1000                           9               1 MAN
1001                           9               1 WOMAN
1002                           9               1 unknown
1003                           9               1 MAN

8 rows selected.
```

Query:

```
SQL> insert into stats_client_test
  2    (codeclient, codeaxestat, codeelementstat, VALEURAXESTATISTIQUECLIENT)
  3  select x.codeclient, 9, 1, 'unknown'
  4  from (select codeclient from stats_client_Test
  5        where codeaxestat = 5
  6        minus
  7        select codeclient from stats_client_Test
  8        where codeaxestat = 9
  9       ) x;

0 rows created.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * From stats_client_Test order by codeaxestat, codeclient;

CODECLIENT           CODEAXESTAT CODEELEMENTSTAT VALEURAXESTATISTIQUECLIENT
-------------------- ----------- --------------- ----------------------------------------
1000                           5               1 JOHN
1001                           5               1 ALICE
1002                           5               1 JIM
1003                           5               1 BOB
1000                           9               1 MAN
1001                           9               1 WOMAN
1002                           9               1 unknown     --> here it is
1003                           9               1 MAN

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hello, I didn't know Minus. I just try INSERT INTO STATS_CLIENT_TEST (CODECLIENT, CODEAXESTAT, CODEELEMENTSTAT, VALEURAXESTATISTIQUECLIENT)
SELECT CODECLIENT, '9' , 1, 'K'
  FROM STATS_CLIENT_TEST
  where CODEAXESTAT='5' and codeclient not in (select codeclient 
From STATS_CLIENT_TEST 
  where CODEAXESTAT='9') which seam to do the job.... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=76bd0c17382fd2af7d3642391a6aec18 is it a good way too?

Comment: As usual, there are several ways to do the job. Pick the one you find the most appropriate. If your code works, feel free to use it.